# Confusión con botones JQuery

Tags: jquery, botón

Tengo un problema con un aplicación web.

En una de las páginas tengo un formulario de usuario y debajo un listado de usuarios.

En el listado cada entrada tiene su propio botón para editar, lo que hace que se rellenen los campos del formulario que permitirá modificar el usuario pulsando el botón guardar.

El problema es que si vuelvo al listado y pulso sobre el botón nuevo, este envía al formulario en blanco para poder crear uno nuevo. El problema es que al pulsar el botón guardar en lugar de añadir, lo que hace es querer modificar dando el consiguiente error.

Por otro lado, si se hace lo contrario, es decir, primero se añade un usuario y luego se quiere modificar, en lugar de modificar actúa como si se quisiera modificar.

En la función del botón guardar he creado la opción para que reconozca si lo que tiene que hacer es un `update` o un `insert`. Esta función trabaja perfectamente cuando es la primera vez que se ejecuta, pero luego ya no funciona y confunde una función con otra.

También ocurre con cualquier otro botón (borrar, buscar, etc.) que actúa según el botón que se ha pulsado por primera vez...

**¿Puede ser que JQuery guarde en memoria la última función ejecutada y no permite ejecutar otra distinta?** Si es así, **¿Se podría hacer de algún modo que "resetee" esa "memoria" para ejecutar una nueva función?**

```
$('#guardar').click(function() {
        console.log("clck en boton nuevo");
        $usuario = $('#idusuarios').val();
        if (guardar === "nuevo") {
            nuevo();
        } else {
            modificar();

        }

    });
```

(...)

```
$('#tblNuevo').click(function() {
        guardar = "nuevo";

        console.log("clck en boton nuevo de la tabla");

        location.href = "#cabecera";
        $('#idusuarios').val("");
        $('#nombre').val("");
        $('#apellidos').val("");
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#password').val("");
        $('#password2').val("");
        $('#perfil').val("");
        $('#idusuarios').prop('disabled', false);
    });



function data_editar() {

    $('#tabla tbody').on('click', 'button.editar', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var table = $('#tabla').DataTable();
        var dato = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        idusuarios = $('#idusuarios').val(dato.idusuarios);
        nombre = $('#nombre').val(dato.nombre);
        apellidos = $('#apellidos').val(dato.apellidos);
        email = $('#email').val(dato.email);
        password = $('#password').val(dato.password);
        password2 = $('#password2').val(dato.password);
        perfil = $('#perfil').val(dato.perfil);
        $('#idusuarios').prop('disabled', true);
        guardar = "modificar";
        location.href = "#cabecera";
         console.log("clck en boton editar de tabla");
    });
}
;
```

Comment: Hola Alfredo, bienvenido a [es.so].  Mientras te contestan, recuerda mirar el [Tour] y [ask] para aprender como funciona este sitio. Un saludo

Comment: Cito "en lugar de modificar actúa como si se quisiera modificar." ?

Comment: Creo que el problema está en la variable "guardar" ya que no le estas poniendo nunca un valor diferente a "nuevo". Si esta variable es la que determina el comportamiento de esta funcionalidad... Deberías cambiar su valor en cada acción.

Comment: En las ultimas lineas de la funcion data_editar está asignandole a guardar el valor "modificar", así que ése no sería el problema.

Comment: Quizás dejando solo el listener (Fuera de la funcion data_editar) funcione, 
o estás llamando a la función data_editar explícitamente en algun lado?

Comment: haz un console.log(guardar) en cada método a ver cual es el que te modifica su valor y si esta marcha como debe hasta el método guardar. está difícil dar una respuesta concreta en tu situación.

Comment: Sería interesante ver los elementos de tu HTML. Puede ser un problema de duplicidad de ids en algún elemento.

Comment: Me temo que el problema no es la variable guardar que funciona perfectamente. El problema está en los botones que no responden como debieran y "asumen" la función del último botón presionado. Es como si se guardara en memoria el primer botón utilizado y los demás lo replicaran. Si se presiona F5 o se refresca la página vuelve a funcionar de forma correcta pero no me interesa que la página se refresque cada dos por tres. Quizás el error esté en el uso del botón que está insertado en cada una de las líneas del datetable.

Comment: Buenas Alfredo, ¿donde estás llamando la function data_editar()? Si no la inicializas, tu funcion al hacer clic en button.editar no funcionará. Si puedes, coloca tu código completo para ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente no tengas declarada la variable global `guardar`.

Yo lo que haría es usar metadatos en el botón `#guardar`:

```
$('#guardar').data().tipoGuardar = "nuevo";
```

o bién:

```
$('#guardar').data().tipoGuardar = "modificar";
```

... en lugar de usar variable global

Comment: Como apunto en los comentarios de mi entrada, el problema no es la variable guardar que funciona bien. Son los todos los demás botones que no funcionan correctamente.  Si el botón pulsado es del de añadir, todos los demás botones añaden, ya sea el de modificar, borrar, etc. Voy a probar a separar en dos archivos distintos el formulario y el datatable, a ver que pasa...

Comment: Si en el #guardar en lugar de un `else` para modificar, haces un `else if (guardar === 'modificar')` te hace algo? A mi me da que la variable no la alimentas correctamente